# How can I display the line numbers when using the pipe directive from ngx-markdown

Tags: angular, markdown, line-numbers

This is my current code:

```
<div [innerHTML]="jsonMarkdown | json | language : 'json' | markdown"></div>
```

It displays the `jsonMarkdown` correct and formatted, however I couldn't get the line numbers to work. I followed the documentation, added the line numbers plugin to `angular.json` but now I'm stuck.

I tried

```
<div [innerHTML]="jsonMarkdown | json | language : 'json' | markdown" lineNumbers></div>
```

but that didn't work.

Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-markdown-puwwnk

Comment: Can you post the necessary code parts, especially those regarding https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-markdown#line-numbers-plugin , preferably as a stackblitz.

Comment: added stackblitz

Comment: Sorry, I'm unable to find the mistake. I tried following the documentation using the `markdown` component, but I can't get it to work. I strongly think it has something to do with incorrect import (eventhough it seems correct)

Comment: Thanks for trying, I'm thinking more and mroe that it is problem of ngx-markdown

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reported it as bug an it will be fixed with 7.1.4 (tonight 26.02.2019)

Github bug report: https://github.com/jfcere/ngx-markdown/issues/135